# How to recover a RSA public key from a byte[] array?

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

I'm wondering if it's possible to recover a RSA public key that I have converted to byte array previously.

```
byte[] keyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
PublicKey publicKey = 
    KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(bytes));
```

For more info [see this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/vstep2.html)

Answer (score 45):

For others who want to get private key instead of public key from byte array:

```
PrivateKey privateKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes));
```

Answer (score -1):

Great answer. Thanks for the link. Just for complete, I found this [Converted secret key into bytes, how to convert it back to secrect key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364338/converted-secret-key-into-bytes-how-to-convert-it-back-to-secrect-key)

```
SecretKey key2 = new SecretKeySpec(data, 0, data.length, "DES");
```

and just worked very well.

Comment: DES is outdated, please don't use.