# RSA Public key getting changed after converting to RSAPublicKeySpec

Tags: java, encoding, cryptography, rsa, public-key

I have a RSA public key material as byte array (the key format is PKCS1). I create a `PublicKey` object out of it using `RSAPublicKeySpec` as shown below.

```
public Key retrievePubKey(byte[] derStuff){ // der stuff is my key material
    KeySpec ks = null;
    Key wrapKey = null;
    try {
        DerInputStream dis = new DerInputStream(derStuff);
        DerValue val = dis.getDerValue();
        BigInteger first = val.getData().getBigInteger();
        BigInteger second = val.getData().getBigInteger();
        ks = new RSAPublicKeySpec(first, second);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "IBMJCE");
        wrapKey = kf.generatePublic(ks);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return wrapKey;
}
```

Then I cast the `Key` to `PublicKey`

```
PublicKey pubKey = (PublicKey) mainObj.retrievePubKey(keyMaterial);
```

Now when I print the key material inside the `pubKey`, I get a different key material.

**original key material**
`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`

**Converted key material**

***When I do `byteArrayToHexString(pubKey.getEncoded());`***

`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`

**Then I try to verify the signature using the new `PublicKey` pubKey - but it fails**

The validityIndicator is false

```
Signature signerVerify = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA", "IBMJCE"); // tried with "RSA" - Failing
        signerVerify.initVerify(pubKey);
        signerVerify.update(dataToBeSigned);
        boolean validityIndicator = signerVerify.verify(signature);
```

The `dataToBeSigned` and `keyMaterial` are taken from [OASIS test cases](http://docs.oasis-open.org/kmip/kmip-cs-profile/v1.0/csprd01/kmip-cs-profile-v1.0-csprd01.html#_Toc374011622)
I've tried several other methods ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867880/convert-byte-array-back-to-public-key/35868083?noredirect=1#comment59718661_35868083)) explained  on stackoverflow but none is working.

Comment: You haven't made clear how you obtained the second key blob but at any rate it's clear they are the same public key, just packaged in slightly different ASN.1 blobs.

Comment: If you look closely, you can see that they are essentially the same, but the second one has additional information: `122300D06092A864886F70D01010105000382010F0030820`

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes, But because of that additional information my signature verification is failing. How can I get rid of that additional info?