# Open source replacement for sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl

Tags: java, encoding, cryptography, rsa, public-key

I get some warnings due to use of RSAPublicKeyImpl:

> warning: RSAPublicKeyImpl is internal proprietary API and may be
>   removed in a future release import sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl;

I have tried to find a replacement, but with no luck. What is the open source alternative for this class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[class `RSAPublicKeySpec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/RSAPublicKeySpec.html) supports at least a part of the implementation that you're looking for. Namely it can be created from the exponent and modulus as BigInteger.

You can use this to get an [RSAPublicKey from an encoded `byte[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411096/how-to-recover-a-rsa-public-key-from-a-byte-array):

```
RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey)KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(
        new X509EncodedKeySpec(bytes));
```

Comment: Just small note for PrivateKey - RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(priv)); works in similar way

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but try Bouncy castle library
https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html

Several mounth ago I also had same issue as you, and I successfully solved it by using AES cryptyng alghoritm

Comment: Thanks, I saw bouncycastle implementation but I was trying to avoid that dependency